# adding attribute which value is another's element's attribute's value

Tags: xslt, xpath

i have xml:

```
<graph>
<node id="a" />
<node id="b" />
<node id="c" />
<node id="d" />

<link from="a" id="link1" to="b"/>
<link from="b" id="link2" to="d"/>
<link from="d" id="link3" to="c"/>

</graph>
```

i want to transform it by xslt to next xml:

```
<graph>
<node id="a">
    <link id="link1" to="b">
</node>
<node id="b">
    <link id="link2" to="d">
</node><node id="c">
<node id="c"/>
<node id="d">
    <link id="link3" to="c">
</node>
</graph>
```

i wrote xslt which inlcudes next part:

```
<xsl:template match="//node">
    <xsl:element name="link">
            <xsl:attribute name="to">
                <xsl:value-of select="//link[@from = self::node()/@id]/@to"></xsl:value-of>
            </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates />     
    </xsl:element>


</xsl:template>
```

but this didn't work. what i'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Your XSLT only creates `link` elements, but you somehow have to create `graph` and `node` elements as well. Also, `self::node()` in a predicate doesn't work as you expect. Use the `current()` function instead.

To solve your task, it's a good idea to start with an identity transform and add templates for nodes that need special handling. Here's an example:

```
<!-- Identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="graph">
    <xsl:copy>
        <!-- Only process node children -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node">
    <xsl:copy>
        <!-- Also process matching links -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | //link[@from = current()/@id]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Don't copy @from attribute of links -->
<xsl:template match="link/@from"/>
```